# Tensorflow function RAM usage keeps rising

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a very simple tensorflow-based function that takes a tensor of shape (1, 6, 64, 64, 64, 1) and returns a tensor of shape (1, 6, 3) containing the centre of mass of each (64, 64, 64) volume in the original tensor. I works without any problems, but every time my loop (see below) goes into the next iteration, the RAM used in my pc increases. This limits me to about 500 samples before I ran completely out. I assume I'm missing something somewhere but I'm not experienced enough to know where.

code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import scipy.io
import scipy.ndimage
import sys
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np

def get_raw_centroids(lm_vol):
    # Find centres of mass for each landmark
    lm_vol *= tf.cast(tf.greater(lm_vol, 0.75), tf.float64)
    batch_size, lm_size, vol_size = lm_vol.shape[:3]
    xx, yy, zz = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(vol_size), tf.range(
        vol_size), tf.range(vol_size), indexing='ij')
    coords = tf.stack([tf.reshape(xx, (-1,)), tf.reshape(yy, (-1,)),
                       tf.reshape(zz, (-1,))], axis=-1)
    coords = tf.cast(coords, tf.float64)
    volumes_flat = tf.reshape(lm_vol, [-1, int(lm_size), int(vol_size * vol_size * vol_size), 1])
    total_mass = tf.reduce_sum(volumes_flat, axis=2)
    raw_centroids = tf.reduce_sum(volumes_flat * coords, axis=2) / total_mass
    return raw_centroids



path = '/home/mosahle/Avg_vol_tf/'
lm_data_path = path + 'MAT_data_volumes/'


files = [f for f in listdir(lm_data_path) if isfile(join(lm_data_path, f))]
files.sort()


for i in range(10):

    sess = tf.Session()
    print("File {} of {}".format(i, len(files)))

    """
    Load file
    """
    dir = lm_data_path + files[i]
    lm_vol = scipy.io.loadmat(dir)['datavol']
    lm_vol = tf.convert_to_tensor(lm_vol, dtype=tf.float64)
```

lm_vol are the (1, 6, 64, 64, 64, 1) arrays. They're just numpy arrays and are converted into tensors.

```
    """
    Get similarity matrix
    """
    pts_raw = get_raw_centroids(lm_vol)
    print(sess.run(pts_raw))
    sess.close()
```

I've tried putting the tf.Session() outside the loop as well but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue in the above code is you are creating multiple graphs inside the loop, when you calling the function `get_raw_centroids`.

Lets consider a simpler example:

```
def get_raw_centroids(lm_vol):
   raw_centroids = lm_vol * 2
   return raw_centroids

for i in range(10):

   sess = tf.Session()
   lm_vol = tf.constant(3)
   pts_raw = get_raw_centroids(lm_vol)
    print(sess.run(pts_raw))
    print('****Graph: ***\n')
    print([x for x in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()])
    sess.close()
```

The output of the above code is:

```
#6
#****Graph: ***

#[<tf.Operation 'Const' type=Const>, 
#<tf.Operation   'mul/y' type=Const>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul' type=Mul>]

#6
#****Graph: ***

#[<tf.Operation 'Const' type=Const>,
# <tf.Operation 'mul/y' type=Const>, 
# <tf.Operation 'mul' type=Mul>, 
# <tf.Operation 'Const_1' type=Const>, 
# <tf.Operation 'mul_1/y' type=Const>, 
# <tf.Operation 'mul_1' type=Mul>]

#6
#****Graph: ***

#[<tf.Operation 'Const' type=Const>,
#<tf.Operation 'mul/y' type=Const>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul' type=Mul>, 
#<tf.Operation 'Const_1' type=Const>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul_1/y' type=Const>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul_1' type=Mul>, 
#<tf.Operation 'Const_2' type=Const>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul_2/y' type=Const>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul_2' type=Mul>]

...
```

So each loop adds a new graph with new variables along with the old graph.

The correct way to handle the above code is the following:

```
# Create a placeholder for the input
lm_vol = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
pts_raw = get_raw_centroids(lm_vol)

# Session    
for i in range(10):

   # numpy input
   lm_vol_np = 3

   # pass the input to the placeholder and get the output of the graph    
   print(sess.run(pts_raw, {lm_vol: lm_vol_np}))
   print('****Graph: ***\n')
   print([x for x in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()])

sess.close()
```

The output of the code will be:

```
#6.0
#****Graph: ***

#[<tf.Operation 'Placeholder' type=Placeholder>,
#<tf.Operation 'mul/y' type=Const>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul' type=Mul>]

#6.0
#****Graph: ***

#[<tf.Operation 'Placeholder' type=Placeholder>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul/y' type=Const>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul' type=Mul>]

#6.0
#****Graph: ***

#[<tf.Operation 'Placeholder' type=Placeholder>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul/y' type=Const>, 
#<tf.Operation 'mul' type=Mul>]
```